# How do I pass an options hash to a module in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, rubygems, activesupport

In reality, I want to configure my gem.

```
require "foo/version"
require "foo/bar"
module Foo
end

require 'securerandom'
require 'active_support'
module Foo
  module Bar
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

      # I would to change this line to something like
      # has_secure_password validations: (validate? true : false)
      has_secure_password validations: true
    end

    module ClassMethods
    end

    extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

I want to load my gem from from the model, something like:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  foo_bar validate: false
end
```

But I have no clue what the Ruby idiom is for something like this. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define class method `foo_bar` within your module which will accept hash and behave accordingly. You could for example do:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def foo_bar(options)
        has_secure_password validations: options[:validate]
      end
    end

    extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

Comment: So, if I can just do that, what's the point of the `included do` method call? Many examples seem to have this pattern.